# Prove that if a random variable $X$ with mean $\mu$ and variance $\sigma^2$ and $\sigma=0$ then $X=\mu$ with probability $1$

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

I'm looking at a question that says if you have a random variable $X$ with mean $\mu$ and variance $\sigma^2$ and $\sigma=0$ then prove that $X=\mu$ with probability 1. I'm pretty sure it has to be solved using Chebyshev's inequality. My approach was,
$$P(|X-\mu|<k\sigma) \geq 1-\frac{1}{k^2}$$
And then assuming that (for the moment) $\sigma > 0$, choose $k=\frac{\epsilon}{\sigma}$ Then taking the limit as $\sigma \rightarrow 0$ would give the result but I'm not sure if that's right. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

You are using a hammer to kill a fly. Recall that
$$
Var(X)=E(X-EX)^{2}
$$
Now if $\sigma_{X}=0$, then $Var(X)=0$. Since $(X-EX)^{2}\ge 0$, if $X$'s value is different from $EX$ with positive probability, you would have
$$
E(X-EX)^{2}=\int_{x:x\not= \mu} f_{X}(x)(x-\mu)^{2}dx>0
$$
Therefore $X$ must be essentially a constant except on a set with probability zero.

Answer (score 1):

Hint : $\mathbb{P}(|X-E(x)|>\epsilon )\leq \frac{\sigma ^2}{\epsilon ^2}=0$ (Markov inequality).